# error in psutil setup command: 'extras_require' must be a dictionary

Tags: python, pip

Is there any idea about how to install `psutil` via `pip`?

```
$ pip install --user psutil
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Collecting psutil
  Using cached psutil-5.7.2.tar.gz (460 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-i8HC1h/psutil/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-i8HC1h/psutil/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-yZhohS
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-i8HC1h/psutil/
    Complete output (3 lines):
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    error in psutil setup command: 'extras_require' must be a dictionary whose values are strings or lists of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: what is your `pip` version?

Comment: pip 20.2.3 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

Comment: Can you please try `pip install --upgrade setuptools` and then try `pip install psutil`

Comment: Right. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pip install --upgrade setuptools`

then you can try `pip install psutil`